# How to show list header with date and monthly expenses total flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, listview

I have list view in flutter application. I user [sticky_grouped_list](https://pub.dev/packages/sticky_grouped_list) for sticky headers and my app look like below screenshot.

[image]

How to show monthly total expenses right of the date header. Exp. total expenses of July 2021 is 1049?

Comment: You Want total like -$240.00 is exact right side of the Transportaition-8/2/2021?

Comment: No, monthly total right side of header. It's August 2021, July 2021.